# ERROR Access Denied when using php file_get_content

Tags: php, file-get-contents, access-denied

I am using php [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to get a webpage.
When i am doing it from my localhost everything works good.
But as soon as i do it from my shared hosting i get this error message:

> ERROR
>   Access Denied
>   Access Denied by security policy
>   The security policy for your network prevents your request from being allowed at this time. Please contact your administrator if you feel this is incorrect.

this is the header i get back

```
array(4) { [0]=> string(22) "HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden" [1]=> string(23) 
"Content-Type: text/html" [2]=> string(17) "Connection: close" [3]=> string(19) 
"Content-Length: 353" }
```

the code is straightforward

```
$page = file_get_contents('http://www.somedomain.com/');
```

if i try for current page it works

```
 $page = file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10565054/error-access-denied-when-using-php-file-get-content');
```

any ideas ?

Comment: Does your shared host have the same php settings and the fopen url wrappers enabled?

Comment: when i read from another domain it works

Comment: check if `allow_url_fopen` is disabled in your shared hosting, i am guessing that is causing the issue.

Comment: It isn't returning false, it is returning a valid HTTP response; it is actually working.  The problem is the Webserver is returning a 403 forbidden.  We need to figure out why.  Can you post some code?  I'm curious if you're setting any context in that file_get_contents call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The remote webserver is rejecting your request.  There's no telling speficically why it is denying you.  It could the server is configured to deny an IP range that includes wherever your shared hosting is.  It could be that the server requires certain header information (like a host entry, or a certain user_agent, or something).Try setting some HTTP context stuff to appease the server you're trying to contact.  Here's an example from the [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) page.

```
function file_get_contents_utf8($fn) { 
    $opts = array( 
        'http' => array( 
            'method'=>"GET", 
            'header'=>"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8" 
        ) 
    ); 

    $context = stream_context_create($opts); 
    $result = @file_get_contents($fn,false,$context); 
    return $result; 
}
```

If you can access the target from your browser, try duplicating allt he headers your browser is sending.  Most browsers have some sort of plugin to show you exactly what headers are going out on the request.

Comment: i tried this but it did not help, i tried from a VPS without setting any headers and it worked, i am guessing that my shared host ip is being denied in the domain i am trying to read from.

Comment: ...or there's a proxy in the way that's messing with you getting to your destination.

Answer (score 0):

So that web server checked the browser and rejected your connection. You should try fsock functions.